# Facebook profile pages

Tags: php, url-routing

How does facebook profile pages work?  I can go to http://www.facebook.com/eric.zoesch and it will actually go to his webpage.  The same with twitter and the whole http://www.twitter.com/@LIAIH

How do i do that?  thanks :)  I guess the only thought i had was to make it so that php generates a page that is like this.

```
<?php 
    ... Do some sql stuff to get the users ID ...
    include_once("$path/Profile/index.php?id=usersid"); 

    echo "Is this the best way to do this?  I really do not know."
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this!!!!

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure how they do it, but likely they use some sort of URL rewriting. A good introduction to the topic is [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). The idea is to make the server automatically translate certain URL requests into other URL requests behind the scenes, e.g. to a PHP page with a query string.

Answer (score 1):

Usually sites use URL rewriting to handle things like this.

Apache offers the mod_rewrite plugin that can rewrite incoming urls from

```
http://.../foo
```

to something like

```
http://.../show_homepage.php?username=foo
```

which happens after the request is accepted by the web server but before PHP gets to see it.

Comment: Well, let me take a look at this stuff, and if its good, then ill give you a correct answer!